# Parenthesis matching in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, sympy

I have string in following way. I need to Extract string from next state and add matching
parenthesis. Do we have function in Python which can do parenthesis matching in Python

```
a) data = [next_state=((!SE&((A1&A2)|(B1&B2)))|(SE&SI))):Q=iq]

b) data = [(next_state=(!SE&((!B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI)),clear=B2&lqn,preset=B2&lq)))]

data_1 = data[0].split(',')
for item in data_1:
    if item.find('next_state=')!= -1:
        item_list = item.split('=')
        item_op = item_list[len(item_list) -1].lstrip('(').rstrip(')')
        item_op = "(" + item_op + ")"
        print item_op
```

`Excepted:((!SE&((A1&A2)|(B1&B2)))|(SE&SI))` (Remove Extra and match pattern)

> if require correct/add missing parenthisis

The code was working fine when I do not have extra parenthesis.But Sometime it can add extra parenthesis for example b case. So it is not generalized solution. is it possible to match parenthesis.

---

I am editing question based on the feedback which I got from below answer.Final version of code.Thanks for providing input. code comment are welcome

```
#!/usr/bin/env py
import itertools
import sys
import sympy
import re
def extract_next_state(s):
    p = re.compile('(\()|(\))')
    depth = 0
    startindex = None
    start_point = False
    for m in p.finditer(s):
        if m.group(1):          # (
            depth += 1
            print "depth (", depth
            if not start_point:
                startindex = m.start()
                start_point = True
        elif m.group(2):          # )
            depth -= 1
            print "depth )", depth
            if depth == 0:
                return s[startindex:m.end()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #data = ['next_state=(~SE&((~B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI))']
    data = ['next_state=((~SE&((A1&A2)|(B1&B2)))|(SE&SI)))']
    data_1 = data[0].split(',')
    com = None
    for item in data_1:
        if item.find('next_state=')!= -1:
            item_list = item.split('=')
            item_op = extract_next_state(item_list[1])
            print item_op
            expr = sympy.sympify(item_op)
            temp_list = [ str(data) for data in expr.free_symbols]
            print temp_list
```

Comment: The code you have supplied has no regular expressions at all, and the  `a` and `b` lines are not valid Python. Please clarify and fix your question. Also - your desire is not clear, please provide a sample input/expected output and any exceptions/stacktrace/messages/errors you may be receiving.

Comment: Did you forgot quotes for your sample data? what is expected output for your function?

Comment: Matching nested structures with regular expressions, especially *nested* structures, is always *painful*. Perhaps you want to find yourself a parser instead.

Comment: What is the expected result for case b? Should it include `,clear=B2&lqn,preset=B2&lq`?

Comment: There is no question in the current version of the post...

Comment: I edited the question back in. Answers without a question are not useful for future visitors.

Comment: Agree with the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def extract_next_state(s):
    p = re.compile('(next_state=)|(\()|(\))')
    depth = 0
    startindex = None
    for m in p.finditer(s):
        if m.group(1):            # next_state=
            startindex = m.end()
        elif startindex is None:  # haven't found 'next_state=' yet
            continue
        elif m.group(2):          # (
            depth += 1
        elif m.group(3):          # )
            depth -= 1
            if depth == 0:
                return s[startindex:m.end()]
            elif depth < 0:
                return s[startindex:m.start()]
    if startindex is None: return None
    return s[startindex:] + ')' * depth

a = '[(next_state=(!SE&((!B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI'
print(extract_next_state(a))
b = '[(next_state=(!SE&((!B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI)),clear=B2&lqn,preset=B2&lq)))]'
print(extract_next_state(b))
```

**Output:**

```
(!SE&((!B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI))
(!SE&((!B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI))
```

Comment: what is the mean of (\()|(\). could not understand

Comment: `( )` captures a value into a group. `\(` and `\)` matches a literal parenthesis.

Comment: so if depth equal to 0, I have all matched parenthesis.if we do not fine than How Will I able to add. I was doing split with euqal  like. data.split('=').  So I was getting (!SE&((!B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI) and missing last one

Comment: @JanneKarila I fixed that too.

Comment: I am trying to understand this code and two question. 1)startindex:m.start() /m.end() what is really does  2) s[startindex:] + ")" * depth. what is purpose of that

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami `s[i:j]` returns the substring between character positions `i` and `j`. `s[i:]` returns the substring between the character position `i` and the end of the string. `m.start()` and `m.end()` returns the starting- and ending-positions of the match (just before and after the parenthesis). The last line is there for the case where the string ends without a closing parenthesis, like the `a` string at the end.

Comment: I could not understand this logic elif depth < 0:
                return s[startindex:m.start()]

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami It is for the case with no parenthesis ( `[(next_state=SE)]`), so that the closing parenthesis won't be included in the result.